# Error pushing nodejs application to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to deploy a nodejs site on heroku. The site runs fine with heroku local, but when I try to push to heroku remote I get the  error blow. Can you please help me out?

```
remote: /tmp/build_75e4a69a5c93328a55b43b1f2ca7ee85/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:79
remote:       var notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
remote:                                                     ^
remote: SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
remote:     at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
remote:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
remote:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
remote:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
remote:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
remote:     at startup (node.js:119:16)
remote:     at node.js:945:3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone else lands here, [matching the node versions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version) worked for me. In your `package.json` file, make sure your current node version matches with the `engines` section:

```json
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "description": "a really cool app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.x"
  }
}
```

Comment: This was the fix for me. I also found it helpful to check the supported runtimes on Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support